# PHP - Concurrent stream_socket_accept connections?

Tags: php, sockets, concurrency

I've been trying to set up a socketserver using stream functions. But one problem is: In my code, I have:

```
while($conn = @stream_socket_accept($server))
{

  $request = "";

  while(substr($request, -4) !== "\r\n\r\n")
  {

    $request .= fread($conn, 1024);

  }

  $headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: PHP " . phpversion() . "\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

  fputs($conn, $headers);

  fclose($conn);

}
```

So, as you can see I fclose($conn), otherwise the headers / HTML is not getting sent to the client, and when I close it, It won't accept any other connections. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

I'm running it on 0.0.0.0:80, so you may try it [here](http://192.168.43.10/)

Comment: Your link points to http://192.168.43.10/, which is within your [private network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) we could not possibly expect to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want to do is:

```
    while (true) {
        $conn = @stream_socket_accept($server);

        if ($conn) {
            $request = "";

            while(substr($request, -4) !== "\r\n\r\n") {
                $request .= fread($conn, 1024);
            }

            $headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: PHP " . phpversion() . "\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

            fputs($conn, $headers);
            fclose($conn);
        }

        // only break out of this loop if you want to close the server
    }
```

Comment: Now I have to actually be on the page running the stream_socket_server() for the client to connect, otherwise the page is stuck on loading, what do I do about that?